# Не могу корректно собрать PHP файл из PUG

Tags: php, wordpress, pug

Верстаю сайт через PUG, хочу посадить его на WordPress. При вставке PHP кода (который вставляет картинку на страницу) в PUG-файл, в конечном PHP-файле вместо символа "<" получается "&lt" и PHP-код не работает.
Вот так пишу в PUG:
`img(src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(SCF::get( 'my_photo' )) ?>", alt="")`
Вот такое получаю в PHP:`<img src="&lt;?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(SCF::get( 'my_photo' )) ?&gt;" alt=""/>`

Использую программу Prepros для сборки файлов.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать, чтобы php собирался корректно.

Comment: Строчку разорвать пробовал? Или экранировать эти символы?

Comment: Разорвать пробовал, не вышло, а вот как экранировать не могу понять. Вычитал, что нужно использовать !{}, но не выходит. Может я неправильно экранирование использую?

Comment: Все, я разобрался с экранированием, спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!= (Не равно) извлекает переменную без экранирования. Нужно было написать вот так: `img(src!="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(SCF::get( 'my_photo' )) ?>;", alt="alt")`
Все заработало, спасибо Pashok за подсказку.